# How to remove default styles from telerik rad tilelist control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a rad tile list control in my window presentation foundation Application. I want to remove the border on mouse over which is default with this control and want to apply my own hover effect and I want also to raise mouse down event so when user click on a tile list item from tablet or any touch device I can redirect this to another page.

```
<telerik:RadTileList>
 <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding homeTileListSelectedItemChangedCommand}" >
                <ie:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <app:TechnicianConverterHome></app:TechnicianConverterHome>
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding ElementName="horizontalListBox" />
                        <Binding ElementName="HomeUserControl" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ie:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </ie:InvokeCommandAction>
        </ie:EventTrigger>
    </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadTileList>
```

Comment: You'll have to find it in the style templates. There's documentation for customizing appearances in Teleriks docs.

Answer (score 1):

Hi in my opinion there is only the one way to change a default behavior of the control. In order to do that you have to change the control's default ControlTemplate. The items inside the RadTileList control collection of views are of Tile type. So let's change the Tile ControlTemplate, and define our desired effects instead of a default.

**Xaml code**

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:Tile" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:Tile}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"/>
                    <Setter Property="flowConfiguration:TileAttachedProperties.IsTyleTypeBound" Value="True"/>
                    <!--these events wil be handled in .xaml.cs file-->
                    <EventSetter Event="TouchDown" Handler="TouchDown_OnHandler"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="MouseDown_OnHandler"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="TileRootPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="10"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid x:Name="ContentVisual" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Content="{Binding 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:Tile}}, 
                                            Path=Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TileContentTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="SelectedVisual" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid Margin="0" x:Name="SelectedSymbol" Background="Blue"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="20" Height="20">
                                            <TextBlock Text="!" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border x:Name="MouseOverVisual" Margin="0" 
                                            Visibility="Collapsed" BorderThickness="1" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="telerik:Tile.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="1.5"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="telerik:Tile.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="telerik:Tile.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedVisual" Value="Blue"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" TargetName="SelectedVisual" Value="2.5"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" TargetName="SelectedVisual" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="telerik:Tile.IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedVisual" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" TargetName="SelectedVisual" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

**Model and ViewModel code**

```
   public class TileReTemplateTestViewModel:Screen
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemTypeWrapper> _items;

    public TileReTemplateTestViewModel()
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<ItemTypeWrapper>(GetInitializedItemCollection());
        DisplayName = "Test";
    }

    private List<ItemTypeWrapper> GetInitializedItemCollection()
    {
        var doubles = new List<ItemType>
        {
            ItemType.Mail, ItemType.Weather
        };
        var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof (ItemType))
            .OfType<ItemType>()
            .Select(type => new ItemTypeWrapper {ItemType = type}).ToList();
        items.ForEach(wrapper =>
        {
            wrapper.IsDouble = doubles.Contains(wrapper.ItemType);
        });
        return items;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemTypeWrapper> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}

public class ItemTypeWrapper:PropertyChangedBase
{
    private ItemType _itemType;
    private bool _isDouble;

    public ItemType ItemType
    {
        get { return _itemType; }
        set
        {
            _itemType = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ItemType);
        }
    }

    public bool IsDouble
    {
        get { return _isDouble; }
        set
        {
            _isDouble = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>IsDouble);
        }
    }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    Mail,
    Market,
    Contacts,
    Weather,
}
```

**Helpers**

```
    public class TileAttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTyleTypeBoundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsTyleTypeBound",
        typeof (bool),
        typeof (TileAttachedProperties),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), IsTyleBoundPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void IsTyleBoundPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tile = sender as Tile;
        var isBound = (bool) args.NewValue;
        if(tile == null || isBound == false) return;
        tile.Loaded += TileOnLoaded;
    }

    private static void TileOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var tile = sender as Tile;
        if (tile == null) return;
        tile.Loaded -= TileOnLoaded;

        var tileContent = tile.Content;
        if (tileContent == null || tileContent is ItemTypeWrapper == false) return;

        var binding = new Binding("IsDouble");
        binding.Source = tileContent;
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        binding.Converter = new Bool2TileTypeConverter();
        tile.SetBinding(Tile.TileTypeProperty, binding);

    }

    public static void SetIsTyleTypeBound(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsTyleTypeBoundProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsTyleTypeBound(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(IsTyleTypeBoundProperty);
    } 
}

internal class Bool2TileTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isDouble = (bool) value;
        return isDouble ? TileType.Double : TileType.Single;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class TileContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Mail { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Market { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Contacts { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Weather { get; set; }


    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate dataTemplate;
        var model = item as ItemTypeWrapper;
        if (model == null) 
            return null;
        var key = model.ItemType;
        switch (key)
        {
            case ItemType.Mail:
                dataTemplate = Mail;
                break;
            case ItemType.Market:
                dataTemplate = Market;
                break;
            case ItemType.Contacts:
                dataTemplate = Contacts;
                break;
            case ItemType.Weather:
                dataTemplate = Weather;
                break;
            default:
                throw  new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return dataTemplate;
    }
}
```

How it look like:
[image]

Regards,

Comment: @ankit added redirection

Comment: How to implement smoothly  touch scrolling in tile list